# QML RichText numbered list isn't aligned correctly depending on font

Tags: qt, qml, richtext

I'm trying to display a text element with `Text.RichText` that contains a numbered HTML list. For some reason the list items 1. and 2. aren't aligned in center if I use Inter font. For any other font it seems to work.
Is there a solution to that problem?

```
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QFontDatabase>

void InstallDefaultFont()
{
    qint32 fontId = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/Inter-Light.ttf");
    QStringList fontList = QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(fontId);
    QString family = fontList.first();
    QGuiApplication::setFont(QFont(family));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    InstallDefaultFont();

    QQuickView view;
    view.resize(QSize(600, 600));
    QQmlContext *context = view.engine()->rootContext();
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Item {
    width: 900
    height: 900

    Label {
        text: "<b>Title</b><br><ol><li>Step #1</li><li>Step #2: list number doesn't align in center</li></ol>"
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 50
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        font.pixelSize: 48
        textFormat: Text.RichText
        font.weight: Font.Medium
        //font.family: "Times"
    }
}
```

### Using Inter-Light.ttf:

[image: Using Inter-Light.ttf]

Using any other font:

[image: Works using any other font]

Comment: The list style is right-aligned, and if the other font appears to be centered-aligned, it is only because the number glyphs of that font have a fixed width size.

Comment: For additional notes, you can't change the list-style alignment, and your only choice is to modify the width of the font's glyphs.

Comment: I'm not familiar with changing fonts glyphs. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can use free tools like [fontforge](https://fontforge.org), But I think you should get over it; it doesn't worth the time you spend. Just use a fixed-size font. However, you should also know that you can't do anything if characters exceed one.